# Transfer data from SQL Server to Firebird using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, firebird

I'm trying to execute a select in SQL Server database and insert the result to Firebird using SSIS.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Which part of it is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to create a connection between SSIS en Firebird. To do this, you need to download the  `LCPI OLE DB Provider for InterBase` first.

When you have that installed, you just select it from the dropdown during the creation of the new connection manager.

Check these links out:

- https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/download.html
- https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/ssis_firebird_interbase.html