# Connecting Firebird db and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, firebird

I would like to connect Firebird db to my SQL Server database. Purpose of this is that I want the SQL Server database refreshed with Firebird data every night, so obviously make a job.

I looked around and saw a lot of tools and drivers that you need to get in order for this to work, and when I looked at them, they are ether a work in progress or a scam.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this reliably?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer data from SQL Server to Firebird using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659152/transfer-data-from-sql-server-to-firebird-using-ssis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) that runs a job in SQL Agent. SSIS supports any OLE-DB or ODBC data source, just set your SQL Server instance as the destination.

Here's an example using Firebird, SSIS and InterBase - but you can skip the parts for InterBase: https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/ssis_firebird_interbase.html