# Connecting to Firebird SQL from SQL Server through ODBC yields an error: "Unable to complete network request to host "xnet://Global\FIREBIRD"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, firebird

I am trying to download data from customer's Firebird SQL database to our SQL Server, through integration package.

In SQL Server Management Studio I right click the target database, select Tasks > Import Data. As Data Source, I pick `*.Net Framework Data Provider for ODBC .*`

I put in my connection string:

```
User=Yano;
Password=p@ssw0rd;
Database=MyDatabase;
DataSource=sql.example.com;
Port=3050;
Dialect=1;
Charset=NONE;
Role=;
Connection lifetime=15;
Pooling=false;
MinPoolSize=0;
MaxPoolSize=50;
Packet Size=8192;
ServerType=0;
```

And driver: `Firebird/InterBase(r) driver`.

[I am sure I have that driver installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66yic.png), and that it is 64-bit version - fitting for my 64-bit system.

Then, trying to continue in the Import wizards, I get following error:

```
ERROR [08004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Unable to complete network request to host "xnet://Global\FIREBIRD".
ERROR [01S00] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
ERROR [01S00] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
ERROR [01S00] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
...
```

After rigorous googling, it seems like the xnet protocol is used internally by Firebird database, when connecting the client to server *locally*. Which is suspicious, since I am trying to connect *remotely*. I have filled the target host (`DataSource=sql.example.com;`) in connection string, so I see no reason for the driver to try and connect to local machine (where no such database exists).

My question is twofold:

1. Why do I get this particular error?
2. How do I make this work? (If it is reasonably possible.)

I am sure the connection string is fine, firewall is open and the server is running, since I can easily use it to connect from C# app using the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/).

I could write simple bridge in C# to migrate the data, but it seems like using the integration package would be more elegant tool for such problem.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659152/transfer-data-from-sql-server-to-firebird-using-ssis) suggest using paid 3rd party tool, but I would strongly prefer solution *without* paid 3rd party tools.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. You've shown what you've tried, great, and you've stated you don't want a tool recommendation (good, that's off topic), so what *are* you asking here?

Comment: @ThomA That's (ironically) very good question. I've edited "question".

Comment: I'm not sure it's related, but SSMS is 32bits, so you likely need 32 bit driver to make it work from it. You can run 64 bits import wizard *outside* of ssms though

Comment: It looks like you consulted https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/ but chose wrong driver section: "ADO.NET provider" instead of "ODBC Driver". Thus you connection string is completely wrong for ODBC.

Comment: @siggemannen Good point, worth investigating. Thanks for an idea.

Comment: @user13964273 This is the connection string I got from the customer's administrator. But it could be it's wrong kind of connection string for what I am trying to do. (It would certainly explain why it does work in C# app.) I am very much noob at this.

Comment: @siggemannen Update: I've tried using the 64-bit import wizard, but to no avail.

Comment: If you're using the ODBC driver, then you should use `DBNAME=sql.example.com/3050:MyDatabase` (or `DBNAME=inet://sql.example.com:3050/MyDatabase`), and most of the other connection properties you specified are not valid for the ODBC driver. See also [Connecting to Firebird from Applications](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fbodbc20/firebird-odbc-driver-20-manual.html#fbodbc205-connection)

Comment: @siggemannen Given the OP gets errors from the actual ODBC driver, it is installed and working.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Nice, that's probably it. (Now I am getting different error, further down the line, lol.) If you will write this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: If you got that connection string from an admin then they must be using "ADO.NET Provider for Firebird", not "for ODBC".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Firebird ODBC driver, then you should use `DBNAME=sql.example.com/3050:MyDatabase` (or `DBNAME=inet://sql.example.com:3050/MyDatabase`), and most of the other connection properties you specified are not valid for the ODBC driver. See also [Connecting to Firebird from Applications](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fbodbc20/firebird-odbc-driver-20-manual.html#fbodbc205-connection) for a list of properties.